# How to test javascript code

Tags: javascript, testing

I need help to test my Javascript code.  I have a method called update, which will move my enemies for my game around the screen.

```
constructor(game, x, y, bulletLayer, frame) {
    super(game, x, y, 'enemy', frame);
    this.bounceTick = Math.random() * 2; }

update() {
    this.bounceTick += .02;
    this.y += Math.sin(this.bounceTick) * 1;
}
```

When writing my test for it this is what I have attempted to do.

```
it("moves position correctly", function() {
this.bounceTick = 2;
enemy.update();
assert.equal(Math.sin(this.bounceTick) *1);
 });
```

This is the error I get- AssertionError: expected NaN to equal undefined.

How would I go about writing a test for the update code to make sure my enemy is moving correctly? I know that I am supposed to set bounceTick to a stationary number since in the class it is being calculated as Math.random() * 2

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error message is that you're passing only one argument to `assert.equal(Math.sin(this.bounceTick) *1);` That function wants two arguments--it's `assert.equal`, meaning you want it to look at two things and see whether they're equal. The `undefined` in the error message indicates the missing second argument. The `NaN` in the message means that your call to `Math.sin()` is returning a bad value that can't be recognized as a number.

Also, it's going to be hard for you to test this aspect of your code, given that you start `bounceTick` as a random value. I have written a similar app, with sprites moving around on the screen. I don't test them with a written test as you're doing here; I simply watch them move on the screen and decide whether it looks right.

I don't know of any effective way to test it as you're doing, because the paths your sprites will follow, as well as their starting positions, won't be predictable.

Comment: You can use a javascript mocking library to mock the behavior of `Math.random()` for the test.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but for my app, I use the physics engine, so my sprites bounce off of each other in unpredictable ways. I guess if OP's sprites are moving on a predefined path, that mock thing could work.